Is it possible to get the property value from a generic parameter from an Expression when there is no instance object?
Let's say I have the below extension method and supporting classes and call it with something like:
AppLogs = await Context.PageAsync<AppLog>(log => log.IsActive == true && log.Text == "foo");

The PageAync method is not pertinent, but it ends up calling GetMenebers:
public static IReadOnlyList<KeyValuePair<T, object?>> GetMembers<T>(this Expression<Func<T, object?>> expression) where T : class, new()
    {
        var visitor = new PropertyVisitor<T>();
        
        visitor.Visit(expression.Body);
        visitor.Path.Reverse();
        
        return visitor.Path;
    }


internal class PropertyVisitor<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    internal readonly List<KeyValuePair<T, object?>> Path = new();

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (!(node.Member is PropertyInfo info))
            throw new ArgumentException("The path can only contain properties", nameof(node));
        

        Path.Add(new KeyValuePair<T, object>(((PropertyInfo)member).Name, ((PropertyInfo)member).GetValue(***NEED OBJ***))));
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}

public class AppLog()
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

The desired result from visitor.Path would be two KeyValuePairs:
Key: "IsActive", Value: true
Key: "Text", Value: "Foo"
Since the call originates without an instance object per se, inferring the parameters via the type, is there a way to get the two property values?
I assume if there is a method, it will not be by using PropertyInfo. But I don't know another way with reflection.
Essentially, I need almost exactly what is seen here but for the values, not names.
UPDATE
I think modifying my visitor as such should work. Will updates shortly.
internal class PropertyVisitor<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    internal readonly List<KeyValuePair<T, object?>> Path = new();

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        // if (!(node.Member is PropertyInfo info))
        //     throw new ArgumentException("The path can only contain properties", nameof(node));
        

        Path.AddRange(ExtractConstants(node));
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
    
    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object?>> ExtractConstants(MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        var constants = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object?>>();
        var constExpression = (ConstantExpression)memberExpression.Expression;
        var valIsConstant = constExpression != null;
        Type declaringType = memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType;
        object declaringObject = memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType;

        if (valIsConstant)
        {
            declaringType = constExpression.Type;
            declaringObject = constExpression.Value;
        }

        var member = declaringType.GetMember(memberExpression.Member.Name, MemberTypes.Field | MemberTypes.Property, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static).Single();

        if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
            constants.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(((FieldInfo)member).Name, ((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(declaringObject)));
        else
            constants.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(((FieldInfo)member).Name, ((PropertyInfo)member).GetGetMethod(true).Invoke(declaringObject, null)));

        return constants;
    }
}


The expression you passed in is not a Func<T, object?>, but a Func<T, bool>, it's still possible, but if you can make some changes to the expression, there's an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78877920/is-it-possible-to-extract-properties-and-values-from-actiont/78878206#78878206

In an example of the expression log => log.IsActive == true && log.Text == "foo", equality (==) is a BinaryExpression, so let's catch binary expressions in the visitor:
internal class PropertyVisitor<T> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    internal readonly List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> Path = new();

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        if(node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Equal) {
            ConstantExpression constantExpression = null;
            MemberExpression memberExpression = null;
            if(node.Right is ConstantExpression right) {
                constantExpression = right;
                memberExpression = (MemberExpression)node.Left;
            } else if(node.Left is ConstantExpression left) {
                constantExpression = left;
                memberExpression = (MemberExpression)node.Right;
            }

            if(constantExpression == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("Only equality to constants supported", nameof(node));
            if(memberExpression == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("The path can only contain properties", nameof(node));

            string name = ((MemberInfo)memberExpression.Member).Name;
            Object @value = constantExpression.Value;
            Path.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>(name, @value));
        }
        return base.VisitBinary(node);
    }
}

Then if call as
var result = GetMembers<AppLog>(log => log.IsActive == true && log.Text == "foo");
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Select(kv => $"Key \"{kv.Key}\", Value \"{kv.Value}\"")));

it produces output:
Key "Text", Value "foo"
Key "IsActive", Value "True"

